# Jquery not invoked on tab change MVC 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Content/Master1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<TGF.class.abc>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#tabContainer').tabs();

        $('#tab1').click(function() {
            GetInfo('method1', '#info1');
        });

        $('#tab2').click(function() {
            GetInfo('method2', '#info2');
        });

        $('#tab3').click(function() {
            GetInfo('method3', '#info3');
        });

    });


    function GetInfo(url, div) {
        debugger;
        $(div).html('Loading...');

        $.ajax({
            Type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            success: function(html) {
                $(div).html(html);
            },
            error: function(html) {
                $(div).html('An Error Occurred.');
            },
            cache: false
        });

    }

</script>

<div id="tabContainer">

    <!-- Tab Names -->
    <ul>
        <li><a id='tab1' href="#info1"><span>name1</span></a></li>
        <li><a id='tab2' href="#info2"><span>name2</span></a></li>
        <li><a id='tab3' href="#info3"><span>name3</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="info1">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Mysharedpage", Model, ViewData); %>
    </div>

    <div id="info2">
      <% Html.RenderPartial("Mysharedpage", Model, ViewData); %>
    </div>

    <div id="info3">
   <% Html.RenderPartial("Mysharedpage", Model, ViewData); %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is my shared page (Mysharedpage.ascx)  ,

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<TGF.dfg.method>>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="class.DataContracts" %>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#SelectAll").click(CheckAll);
    });
       function CheckAll() {
            $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#SelectAll').is(':checked'));
        }



</script>
```

Now, the issue is when I click tab1 then it works as usual, i.e. the CheckAll() function on the shared page (Mysharedpage.ascx) works. But when I click on tab2 or tab 3 , the Jquery CheckAll() function is not called and is not working.
Basically the Jquery is not getting called when clicked on tab2 or tab3. All the 3 tab call the same shared (.ascx) page

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is event handlers do not attach themselves to the dynamically added elements to the page try

```
$("#SelectAll").on("click",CheckAll);
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `#SelectAll` in the sample code, but I assume it's part of the dynamically-provided content.

You need to delegate to an ancestor element as a listener, but one that is NOT destroyed when the new content is flown in from the server.

```
$('#tabContainer').on('click', '#SelectAll', CheckAll);
```

I have to admit, I'm somewhat missing the big picture seeing pre-rendered code (I don't work with .NET at all, never mind MVC-2)... but it LOOKS like the CheckAll function is being flown into each of the 3 areas. The code should really be outside, as ONE instance only, on the main page.

Also, if MVC-2 restricts you to a particular version of jQuery (pre 1.7) you will not have the `.on()` function available. For previous versions of jQuery you could use `.delegate()` instead. Part of the syntax is simply flip-flopped:

```
$('#tabContainer').delegate('#SelectAll', 'click', CheckAll);
```